# How to update all rows from Salary Column in Employee table?Below is my code

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I want to update all employee salary using **PL/SQL oracle**.Here is my code.

```
DECLARE 
           c_id customers.id%type; 
           c_sal  customers.salary%type; 
        BEGIN 
       SELECT  salary  
       INTO  c_sal 
       FROM customers; 

       IF (c_sal <= 6500) THEN 
          UPDATE customers  
          SET salary =  salary + 1000;


          dbms_output.put_line ('Salary updated'); 
       END IF; 

    END; 
    /
```

So here is the Employee Table:

select * from customers;

```
ID  NAME     AGE    ADDRESS                     SALARY
1   Ramesh   32     Ahmedabad                   3000
2   Khilan   25     Delhi                       1500
3   kaushik  23     Kota                        2000
4   Chaitali 25     Mumbai                      6500
5   Hardik   27     Bhopal                      8500
6   Komal    22     MP                          4500
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Oracle? (Don't tag products not involved.)

Comment: Using Oracle...

Comment: "Saying some error" - can you be more specific than that?

Comment: Can you please correct my code or any suggestion how to do that?

Comment: I would recommend you use a cursor, that wraps around this code and calls it for every ID.

Comment: DECLARE 
           c_id customers.id%type; 
           c_sal  customers.salary%type; 
        BEGIN 
       SELECT  salary  
       INTO  c_sal 
       FROM customers ;
       IF (c_sal <= 6500) THEN 
          UPDATE customers  
          SET salary =  salary + 1000;


          dbms_output.put_line ('Salary updated'); 
       END IF; 

    END; 
    /

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your question, you want to update `all the rows in Employee` table having `salary <= 6500`. So you don't need any variable or select query. You can have a simple update statement in your procedure. No any need of `DECLARE` section.

```
BEGIN 
 UPDATE customers  
 SET salary = salary + 1000
 WHERE salary <= 6500;
 COMMIT;
 dbms_output.put_line ('Salary updated');

 EXCEPTION
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
   dbms_output.put_line ('No any employee is having Salary <= 6500.');
END; 
/
```

As you want to have `IF-ELSE`, you can do that with the cursor. However I will always go with first option shown above. Below is the code with cursor that uses `IF-ELSE`:

```
DECLARE 
  CURSOR my_cursor IS select * FROM customers;
BEGIN
  FOR r1 in c1
   LOOP
     IF (r1.salary <= 6500) THEN
      UPDATE customers c SET c.salary = (c.salary + 1000) WHERE c.id = r1.id;
      -- If id is not primary/unique key, use WHERE CURRENT OF c1
     END IF;
     COMMIT;
   END LOOP;
END; 
/
```

Comment: `Commit;` or `Rollback` anyone?

Comment: This answer is correct but the thing is i want the condition like if salary is less then 6500,i need if else statement.
Please re-write the query.Thank you.

Comment: But why you want to make it complex when it can be done in a single step ?

Comment: So we are just going to assume that `ID` is the key?

Comment: From sample data, Yes. Or we can also say `WHERE CURRENT OF c1` instead of  `WHERE c.id = r1.id`.

Comment: ok.. @KeyurPanchal ..its is helpful. But still i don't want to use  Cursor.

Comment: That's the only option. In the situation that you are talking, you cannot iterate through all the records without using cursor in PL/SQL.

Answer (score -1):

```
DECLARE
c_id customers.id%type := 1; 
c_sal  customers.salary%type; 
        BEGIN 
       SELECT  salary  
   INTO  c_sal 
   FROM customers 
   where id=c_id;
   IF (c_sal <= 6500) THEN 
      UPDATE customers  
      SET salary =  salary + 1000;
      dbms_output.put_line ('Salary updated'); 
   END IF; 

END; 
/
```

Comment: The Answer is Correct but my query is to UPDATE all employee salary .Here you are updating only where id=1;